# Dockerfile: Install PHP from source, docker-php-ext-install not working

Tags: php, docker

I'm building a base image that installs PHP from source and I'm trying to install some extensions. I'm finding some discrepancies in the extension installations and looking for some clarity. I'm excluding some parts of the Dockerfile here.

```
FROM private-registry:hardened-ubuntu20:latest as base

COPY --from=php:7.4-fpm /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install
COPY --from=php:7.4-fpm /usr/local/bin/docker-php-source /usr/local/bin/docker-php-source
COPY --from=php:7.4-fpm /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable
COPY --from=php:7.4-fpm /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-configure /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-configure
COPY --from=php:7.4-fpm /usr/local/bin/phpize /usr/local/bin/phpize
COPY --from=php:7.4-fpm /usr/src/php.tar.xz /usr/src/php.tar.xz

ENV PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php

RUN apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install -y \
        #PHP extension requirements


RUN docker-php-source extract \
    && cd /usr/src/php \
    && ./configure \
        --enable-fpm \
        --with-fpm-user=www-data \
        --with-fpm-group=www-data \
        --enable-mysqlnd \
        --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
        --enable-mbstring \
        --with-openssl \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && docker-php-source delete
```

When I run `./configure` for the PHP installation with the required extensions, everything seems to install correctly, and my child images are able to pick them up.

Though, in the above snippet, if I remove the `--enable-mbstring` line and try to install it using `docker-php-ext-install mbstring`, the child images do not seem to have the extension installed. The .ini file is created in `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d` as expected, and it appears in the child images, but the requirement is not met. The same goes if I remove `--enable-mysqlnd` and try installing with `docker-php-ext-install mysqli`.

So to consolidate, if I omit any of the configuration options, and only use `docker-php-ext-install` to install my extensions, the installations don't seem to work. I could include all the required extensions in the `./configure` call in the base image, but this is problematic because some of the child images throughout our system are calling `docker-php-ext-install` within their Dockerfiles and we want to be able to change the base image without requiring any changes to the child images. Bottom line is, `docker-php-ext-install` has to work.

**For example**:

```
FROM parent-image-with-php-from-source
...
docker-php-ext-install bcmath
...
```

**Child Image Build Output**: bcmath seems to install correctly, but in a later layer the requirement is not met.

```
...

PATH="$PATH:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/src/php/ext/bcmath/modules
----------------------------------------------------------------------              
Libraries have been installed in:                                                                          
   /usr/src/php/ext/bcmath/modules
                                                                                                                       
If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries                                         
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and                              
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:                                                                                                                                                   
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution                         
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.


...


Step 21/29 : RUN composer install     --no-cache        --no-scripts    --no-autoloader         --no-ansi       --no-dev        --optimize-autoloader   --no-interaction        --no-progress   --prefer-dis
t
 ---> Running in ace1fd609a27
Installing dependencies from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-bcmath * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's bcmath extension.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for s1lentium/iptools v1.1.1 -> satisfiable by s1lentium/iptools[v1.1.1].
    - s1lentium/iptools v1.1.1 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for sabre/http 5.1.1 -> satisfiable by sabre/http[5.1.1].
    - sabre/http 5.1.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - s1lentium/iptools v1.1.1 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - casbin/casbin v2.4.0 requires s1lentium/iptools ^1.1 -> satisfiable by s1lentium/iptools[v1.1.1].
    - Installation request for casbin/casbin v2.4.0 -> satisfiable by casbin/casbin[v2.4.0].

The command '/bin/sh -c composer install     --no-cache         --no-scripts    --no-autoloader         --no-ansi       --no-dev        --optimize-autoloader   --no-interaction        --no-progress   --pr
efer-dist' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Any insight would greatly be appreciated. I'm wondering if it could be as simple as modifying the Path, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue -

I needed to add the following flags to my `./configure` call

```
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d \
--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php \
```

Now, the child images know where to look for the docker-php-ext-*.ini files